# Redirecting or rewriting non-www/wildcard to www.domain.com

Tags: dns, amazon-web-services, web-hosting

I want to redirect the non www thats domain.com to www.domain.com. I know there are lot of people who had already posted the same question here. I went through most of them, realized my case is  little different. I was running my e-commerce application on AWS EC2 instances with load balancer on it and also the DNS was parked in route 53. Very recently we integrated with Akamai so we had to change with CNAME and change the domain name to from domain.com www.domain.com so that we can serve our customers via Akamai. But the problem what we are facing it we are unable to redirect domain.com to www.domain.com. Since Route53 doesnt not all 301 redirection, we re-parked our domain to godaddy, which has got a domain forwarding feature. I tried to redirect using domain forwarding also, but it seems to be not helping us enough.

Presently we are using wwwzier.com to redirect the traffic, planning to have a .htaccess. Since its a commerce between and the site is expected to load faster we cant have a server level redirection or rewrite.

What are the other ways to achieve the same.

DO kindly help me since I am fighting with this fire since a week now.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you considered setting up a dedicated AWS instance with a web server that just does the 301 to www, and pointing the base domain(s) there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I did was setup a micro instance with apache running. Micro instances are free for a year. I opened up port 80 directly to it in security group. Then assigned an elastic ip to it. Then I pointed the A records for my domain(s) to that IP. For the micro instance I just picked the amazon linux ami I think. I SSHed in and I put the following .htaccess in /var/www.

/var/www is usually the default web page for an apache server that's just been setup.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

This basically redirects all whatever.com to their www.whatever.com equivalent.

So now for any domain that you want to redirect to www you can just set the A record for that domain to the elastic ip of your micro instance and that htaccess will redirect anything through to the www version so that the cname pointing to your ELB can take effect.

Comment: Will this also carry over the URL that was originally viewed? ie `http://domain.com/category/page` will redirect to `http://www.domain.com/category/page` ?

Comment: I think so. The $1 should carry that over. "the part of the URL after the hostname and port, and before the query string" http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule So it seems ?a=b query string would be dropped. We stopped using this in favor of route53. You want to test this and report findings here?